# Trello Card Update API

Tags: javascript, trello

I have been trying to play around a little with Trello's REST API. So far I am able to push some cards into the system with the regular POST call. What I would like to do now is to update a card with new information (i.e. new description, new comments or move the card to new list etc.).

Can I do this with a PUT- or a POST-method or do I first need to delete the old card and create a new one? If so, could anybody give an example of how they're doing this?

I've tried the following PUT-method, but it didn't seem to work:

```
PUT https://api.trello.com/1/cards/[existing card id]?key=[key]&token=[TOKEN]
```

and then I'll supply the parameters in the body of the request, like this:

```
{
    "id": "542de77c832cff3f97884ad8",
    "badges": {
        "votes": 0,
        "viewingMemberVoted": false,
        "subscribed": false,
        "fogbugz": "",
        "checkItems": 0,
        "checkItemsChecked": 0,
        "comments": 0,
        "attachments": 0,
        "description": true,
        "due": null
    },
    "checkItemStates": [],
    "closed": false,
    "dateLastActivity": "2014-10-03T00:02:04.042Z",
    "desc": "test",
    "descData": null,
    "due": null,
    "idBoard": "5417684179931e027c3d6bb9",
    "idChecklists": [],
    "idList": "5417684179931e027c3d6bbc",
    "idMembers": [],
    "idShort": 14,
    "idAttachmentCover": null,
    "manualCoverAttachment": false,
    "labels": [],
    "name": "new test #1 updated",
    "pos": 131072,
    "shortUrl": "https://trello.com/c/XYZ",
}
```

By the way, I am using Postman Client to execute my HTTP-methods. In the end I want to implement these functions into a small javascript module. Does anyone have an idea what I am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: "and then I'll just add the updated Ticket as a JSON-file" - what do you mean by this?  You should supply parameters either in the body of the request or as url parameters.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. That's what I actually meant. Sorry for the confusion. I have updated my question. So I hope, it now is a bit clearer...

Comment: You should only include the fields you are changing in the parameters.  Many of the fields you're trying to set are calculated and thus read-only.  Please consult [the documentation](https://trello.com/docs/api/card/index.html#put-1-cards-card-id-or-shortlink) for which fields you can set.

Comment: Thanks again. Nothing happens even if I only try to update the name with the PUT-method... I only get the ticket back as response with the name-field not changed.

Comment: I can now update the card, but only using the changed values as url params and not in my body. Any ideas why this is?

Comment: In Postman you want to use `x-www-form-urlencoded` body.

Answer (score 4):

Allright so it has been quite some time but now I faced the same issue the last few hours. For me the trick with the `x-www-form-urlencoded` body didn't work out.

For the people that are still struggling:

1.) Every parameter you want to change has to be defined in the **Query-Params** - no body is needed

2.) make sure to type in the URL as `https://` and not `http://`! This actually solved the issue.

It seems like the Trello Api interprets every `http://` request as GET.

have fun! :-)

Comment: putting the parameters directly in the url solved my problem, thanks

Comment: Removing request body helped me! I had duplicated another endpoint to create my update request in Postman, and having that request body there yielded the following error: {
    "message": "Invalid objectId",
    "error": "ERROR"
}

Answer (score 0):

Using insomnia rest client, it worked using PUT + body content as json. Adding fields in the url wasn't necessary.

```
* Preparing request to https://api.trello.com/1/cards/card_id?key=your_key&token=some_token
* Current time is 2020-08-07T11:28:18.144Z
* Using libcurl/7.69.1 OpenSSL/1.1.1g zlib/1.2.11 brotli/1.0.7 libidn2/2.1.1 libssh2/1.9.0 nghttp2/1.40.0
* Using default HTTP version
* Disable timeout
* Enable automatic URL encoding
* Enable SSL validation
* Enable cookie sending with jar of 1 cookie
* Found bundle for host api.trello.com: 0xa7f54da37800 [can multiplex]
* Re-using existing connection! (#4) with host api.trello.com
* Connected to api.trello.com (96.7.239.40) port 443 (#4)
* Using Stream ID: 3 (easy handle 0xa7f54da37800)

> PUT /1/cards/card_id?key=your_key&token=some_token HTTP/2
> Host: api.trello.com
> user-agent: insomnia/2020.3.3
> cookie: dsc=blablabla
> content-type: application/json
> accept: */*
> content-length: 20

{"desc":"123123123"}

* We are completely uploaded and fine
```